# How to show ArcGIS Server TileLayer within a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, arcgis-server

I am trying to show a map that I published using ArcGIS Server within a Leaflet map. I first tried to show the map as a basemap and creating a simple Leaflet TileLayer:

```
    var aLayerSix = L.tileLayer('http://seasnail.csun.edu/ArcGIS/rest/services/GIS/Campus_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
                    attribution: 'Map Tile © CSUN Geography'
                });
```

I couldn't get the map. Then I tried to use Leaflet ESRI plugin:

```
var aLayerSix = L.esri.tiledMapLayer("http://seasnail.csun.edu/ArcGIS/rest/services/GIS/Campus_Base/MapServer/");
```

Still I cannot get the Leaflet to show the map. 
Here is the center of the map:

```
var centerlatlng = L.latLng(34.238716626866484, -118.52985978131983);
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your service is in WGS84 (EPSG 4326); it [must be in Web Mercator](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet#tiledmaplayer) (EPSG 3857) to show up in Leaflet.